# In robot framework Can we use Element Should Be Visible in Run Keyword If

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

I am using this code:

```
Run Keyword If Element Should Be Visible    ${PO_Mail_Subject}
```

I'm using Element Should Be Visible in Run Keyword If and getting `Evaluating expression 'Element Should Be Visible' failed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)`.

I don't know whether my code is valid or not. Can anyone help me out!!

Comment: My requirement is to verify whether the subject content is present or not if present I will validate the content of that mail or I will iterate to get the mail which contains a particular text in its subject and open the mail then I will validate that mail content.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Can you please not use the comments for information that is essential to your question and instead use the [edit] functionality to update your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it in this way:

```
${Status}=    Run Keyword And Return Status     Element Should Be Visible ${PO_Mail_Subject}
Run Keyword If    '${Status}'=='TRUE'     Element Text Should Be    <Locator>    <Mail Content>    ELSE    < Do iteration Operation>
```